# Fixing the NetworkOnMainThreadException without using async codes

Tags: java, exception, networking, jsoup, networkonmainthread

I want to have an application use networking operation on its main thread without it throwing a NetworkOnMainThreadException. I don't want to use async codes to get around this. I heard that you can get around the NetworkOnMainThreadException without using async codes by using this code instead, from this answer link: "[How to fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)"

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

The answer stated that you can use this code in the class and it would ignore the NetworkOnMainThreadException and the code would execute without any problems, but when I tried it in my class I got the "identifier expected" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }



    public class myClass {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        public void connect(View v) throws IOException {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com//").get();

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Why? It's a very poor technique, as the dozens of comments say. Use the accepted answer.